# Trivial tangent bundle not diffeomorphic to 2n-dimensional open set

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism, tangent-bundle

I was trying to find an explicit example of a trivial tangent bundle, i.e. $TM = M\times \mathbb{R}^n$, with $M$ a smooth manifold without boundary of dimension $n\in\mathbb{N}$, which is not diffeomorphic to any open subset $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

It seems, but maybe I'm wrong, that all the easy classical example of trivial tangent bundle are actually diffeomorphic to some open $2n$-dimensional set. For instance, take the circle $S^1$, its tangent bundle is a cylinder $S^1\times\mathbb{R}$. We can parametrize it as
$$
\\\{
(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3
,
x^2+y^2=1
\},
$$
and by dilating/schrinking it a bit and projecting it on the $z=0$ plane we obtain that it is diffeomorphic to an open annulus: take
$$
C
=
\{
(x,y,z),
\;
x^2+y^2
=
\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan z + 2
\}
$$
The projection of $C$ on the plane $z=0$ is one-to-one and its image is the open annulus $A=\{ 1 < x^2+y^2 < 3 \}$.

The 2D-torus doesn't work either, because it's diffeomorphic to $S^1\times S^1$ and adapting the previous argument one obtain again that the tangent bundle is diffeomorphic to an open set of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

I have also considered some examples of Lie groups, for instance $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$,
but also this fails since it can be seen as $S^1\times\mathbb{R}^2$ and again one can apply the same argument.

Does anyone know a nice example?

EDIT: I'd rather appreciate a solution that takes into account the case of $M$ a non-compact manifold (even though I don't know if it changes anything).

Comment: The [Whitney embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem) gives an _embedding_ of $M$ into $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. This means that you can change the image of $M$ into a "fat" version of itself (because there is room to do so, it's an embedding) which is basically what you are searching for. But I do not know how to make this formal.

Comment: It is always the case that $TM\times\mathbb{R}$ is diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$, but it's not clear whether one can conclude that $TM$ is diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. For example, $S^{2n}\times\mathbb{R}$ is diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$, but $S^{2n}$ is not diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

Answer (score 2):

Since every smooth manifold embeds into $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ by $\iota: M\to \mathbb{R}^{2n}$, the tubular neighborhood theorem tells us that if $M$ is compact there is a diffeomorphism $\Phi: N(M)\to U$ for some open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^{2n}$, where $N(M)$ is the normal bundle of $M$ corresponding to this embedding. Because in this case $\iota^* T\mathbb{R}^{2n}\cong TM\oplus N(M)\cong (\mathbb{R}^{n}\times M)\oplus (\mathbb{R}^n\times M)$, we see that by applying any bundle isomorphism $TM\to N(M)$, we yield a diffeomorphism $TM\to N(M)\to U$. Things may be somewhat more subtle in the noncompact case.

Comment: I don't understand why there is a bundle isomorphism $TM\rightarrow N(M)$.   I agree that $N(M)$ is stably trivial, but why is it trivial?  Note that for vector bundles, if $E_1\oplus E_2 \cong E_1\oplus E_3$, we cannot conclude that $E_2\cong E_3$.  For example, letting a numeral stand for a trivial bundle of that rank, we have $TS^2\oplus 1 = 3 = 2 + 1$ but $TS^2\neq 2$.

Comment: The normal bundle of an embedding of a parallelisable manifold into a parallelisable manifold need not be trivial, see [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1847264/39599).